# Using ScyllaDB NoSQL kotlin / java

Tags: java, kotlin, nosql, scylla

For a while I have been trying to find out how to use ScyllaDB in Java / Kotlin but in NoSQL, I specify NoSQL! So I would need a module to do that I imagine but I can not find. If someone knows could he help me?

Comment: Could you edit your post with more details around what you're trying to do?  If you're trying to find a driver (which I _think_ you might be), you may have better luck searching for a "Cassandra driver."

Comment: ScyllaDB is compatible with cassandra, so you could use any of the cassandra Java driver to connect to Scylla. https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/integrations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in using ScyllaDB with Java, here's a link to the Java Driver page:

https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/drivers/cql-drivers/scylla-java-driver/

The Scylla Java driver is shard-aware and token aware, which will provide greater performance.

If you are interested in consuming our Change Data Capture (CDC) data, we even have a Java library specifically for that:

https://github.com/scylladb/scylla-cdc-java